# How to resolve "Unable to locate theme engine" type error in Android SDK manager?

Tags: android

I am getting this error while running my Android SDK using eclipse on Ubuntu.

```
(java:5986): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap", [2013-06-06 14:04:53 - SDK Manager]
```

Also when I'm creating a project, automatic generated class file "R" is not either form or going anywhere, please tell solution to this problem also.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

from [morpoint.com](http://www.morpoint.com/ubuntu-11-10-java-gtk-warning-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module_path-pixmap/)